# ForEach issues, a non-match is not skipping the associated step

Tags: powershell, scripting

This code block tries to verify the last blip of a string to the samaccountname of members in a Security Group have corresponding 'Report to $' groups, if a $ in a group name is not found in a security group then remove the Report to AD group...

That's not the best explanation in the world.. the code might make more sense:

```
import-module activedirectory
$ou = "ou=test1, ou=test, ou=company, dc=domain, dc=net"
$ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'
$global:DebugPreference = "continue"

$managers = get-adGroupMember -identity "CN=All Managers,OU=Organizational,OU=Groups,OU=company,DC=domain,DC=net" | 
    select samaccountname
$ReportTogroup = Get-ADGroup -Searchbase $ou -filter "Name -like 'Report to *'" | select-object -expandproperty name


Foreach ($Report in $ReportToGroup ) {
    $report = $report -replace ("Report to ","")
    write-host $report "is the name"
     if ($Report -notin $managers) 
        {Remove-ADGroup -Identity $Report
         write-warning "$Report removed"  
        } else {
          write-host "$Report not removed"
}}
```

Currently if I runt his I get the following:

```
paul.b is the report name
WARNING: paul.b removed
don.h is the report name
WARNING: don.h removed
dave.h is the report name
WARNING: dave.h removed
mike.s is the report name
WARNING: mike.s removed
masako.a is the report name
WARNING: masako.a removed
anna.s is the report name
WARNING: anna.s removed
```

I've stepped through using the ISE debugger and the `$report` variable returns a firstname.lastname which is correct.. same formatting as the SamAccountName for our user objects.  `$managers` does return a getType() array of SamAccountNames... so that should be correct.  And `if ($report -notin $managers)` should have been $false to every name above.  I expected the if/else to trip over to else on those names but it's not.

`$managers` returns lower case values.. so I would not think it's a case issue.

Any help to put me back on the path will be greatly appreciated..

Comment: On $managers =, use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName` aswell to get a **string** array of just SamAccountNames, not an array of **objects** with a property called SamAccountName.

Comment: Oh wow Theo, my scripts not complete but you sir have totally broken this blocker down. My hats off to you. If you throw this as an answer I shall reward you with internet points.  Question though.. how do you know when to use -expandproperty?

Comment: Posted answer ;)

Comment: P.S. `Select-Object` returns objects with one or more properties. If you want the **value** of such a property, you use `-ExpandProperty`. In this case you'll get an array of strings from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are retrieving a **string** array using

```
$ReportTogroup = Get-ADGroup -Searchbase $ou -filter "Name -like 'Report to *'" | select-object -expandproperty name
```

You do not do the same for the $managers into which you receive an array of **objects**, each having a single property called 'SamAccountName' by using `select samaccountname`.

When looping over the strings in `$ReportTogroup` and testing with `if ($Report -notin $managers)`, you are testing if a string is not to be found in a collection of objects, so the result of that will always be `$true`.

Easy fix though, just get an array of manager SamAccountNames as **string** array using

```
$managers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "CN=All Managers,OU=Organizational,OU=Groups,OU=company,DC=domain,DC=net" | 
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
```

Better yet, `Get-ADGroupMember` can also return objects of type `computer` or `group`, so you should filter to get users only:

```
$managers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "CN=All Managers,OU=Organizational,OU=Groups,OU=company,DC=domain,DC=net" | 
            Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
```